# How to load SoundTouchSharp?

Tags: c#

I'm using the library, SoundTouchSharp, in my project. How do I create an instance of it? I don't really understand if I need to use the "using" line and if I need anything else so that I can eventually get

```
SoundTouchSharp s = new SoundTouchSharp();
```

because right now the compiler says:

> "the type or namespace name `SoundTouchSharp` could not be found."

I included `SoundTouchSharp` as a reference (after creating a .dll version of the .cs file), and I also put both SoundTouchSharp.dll and soundtouch.dll in the bin/Debug folder.

So now what?

Comment: What namespace do they create?

Comment: Um, is it BigMansStuff.PracticeSharp.SoundTouchSharp? Here's the library, sorry I'm inexperienced with C#. https://code.google.com/p/practicesharp/source/browse/trunk/PracticeSharpApp/Core/SoundTouchSharp.cs?r=157

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I included SoundTouchSharp as a reference (after creating a .dll
>   version of the .cs file), and I also put both SoundTouchSharp.dll and
>   soundtouch.dll in the bin/Debug folder.

If you want to use the `SoundTouchSharp` class from the `BigMansStuff.PracticeSharp.Core` namespace in another namespace you have to make it public and then create the library.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BigMansStuff.PracticeSharp.Core
{
    /// <summary>
    /// .NET C# Wrapper to the SoundTouch Native C++ Audio library
    /// </summary>
    /// <see cref="http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/index.html"/>
    public class SoundTouchSharp: IDisposable
    {
         //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Then in your project you have to add a *using directive* that allows to use that type from the namespace:

```
using BigMansStuff.PracticeSharp.Core;
```

Comment: It worked!! Thanks so much, Fuex and SLaks! I typed in "using BigMansStuff.PracticeSharp.SoundTouch;" and no more squigglies!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `using` statement to include the namespace that the class is defined in:

```
using BigMansStuff.PracticeSharp.Core;
```

Comment: I tried "using BigMansStuff.PracticeSharp.SoundTouch" and ".Core" but still says the namespace could not be found. :/ Got anything else?